# Regular expression replace a string pattern

Tags: sql, regex, replace

I am trying to check best and optimal way to exclude a pattern of string from a column, without affecting actual data.

With in Redshift DW, I have table column company which has certain records ending with INC in different ways so want to exclude string patterns of INC and capture just company name. Please see below sample data and expected output.

```
WITH T AS (
    select 'Cincin,Inc' id
    union all
    select 'Tinc, INc.' id 
    union all
    select 'Cloud' id 
    union all
    select 'Dinct Inc.' id 
)

select id , regexp_replace(id,{exp}) from T


/**OutPut***/
Cincin
Tinc
Cloud
Dinct
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redshift doesn't support case insensitivity with regex, but given your target string is small, you can work around it without too much pain by using `[Ii][Nn][Cc]`:

```
regexp_replace(id, ',? *[Ii][Nn][Cc]\.?$', '')
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/32799).

---

Test:

```
WITH T AS (
    select 'Cincin,Inc' id
    union all
    select 'Tinc, INc.' id 
    union all
    select 'Cloud' id 
    union all
    select 'Dinct Inc.' id 
)    
select id , regexp_replace(id, ',? *[Ii][Nn][Cc]\.?$', '') from T
```

Output:

```
Cincin
Tinc
Cloud
Dinct
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the pattern `,?\s*Inc\.?$`:

```
select id, regexp_replace(id, ',?\\s*[Ii][Nn][Cc]\\.?$', '') from T
```

Comment: It wouldn't work for records - Tinc, INc.
Dinct Inc.

Comment: Well do you want as output in this case?

Comment: Wanted to remove INC for all records ending with  ',Inc'  ' , Inc'  ' , Inc.'  '  Inc.'  If possible case insensitive pattern INC or inc or InC etc...O/P as mentioned in code- Cincin
Tinc
Cloud
Dinct

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if you are not particluar about the case

```
WITH T AS (
select 'Cincin,Inc' id
union all
select 'Tinc, INc.' id 
union all
select 'Cloud' id 
union all
select 'Dinct Inc.' id
```

)

```
select id , regexp_replace(lower(iD),'[^a-z]+(inc)([^a-z])*','') 
from T
```

output :

```
  id        regexp_replace
Cincin,Inc  cincin
Tinc, INc.  tinc
Cloud       cloud
Dinct Inc.  dinct
```